# Vibrate Myo Armband programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, myo

How can I can vibrate Myo programmatically.

I could vibrate in `TLMHubDidConnectDeviceNotification`, but I could use it in `TLMMyoDidReceiveOrientationEventNotification` because in this notification a don't have a instance of `TLMMyo`.

**Eg:** Vibration in `TLMHubDidConnectDeviceNotification`

```
TLMMyo *myo = notification.userInfo[kTLMKeyMyo];

[myo vibrateWithLength:TLMVibrationLengthLong];
[myo vibrateWithLength:TLMVibrationLengthMedium];
[myo vibrateWithLength:TLMVibrationLengthShort];
```

I also try to save the instance in a `@property` but in `TLMMyoDidReceiveOrientationEventNotification`this instance is `nil`.

PS: [Question in Myo Developer Forum](https://developer.thalmic.com/forums/topic/2841/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like there's a bug with that notification. In the meantime, you can access `TLMMyo`s on the `TLMHub` singleton's `myoDevices` method. If you're using multiple Myo devices, you can identify the one you want to use using the `identifier` property on `TLMMyo`.

I'll look into getting the notification fixed in the long term though.

```
TLMMyo *myo = [[[TLMHub sharedHub] myoDevices] firstObject];

if (myo.identifier == self.identifier) {
    [myo vibrateWithLength:TLMVibrationLengthLong];
    [myo vibrateWithLength:TLMVibrationLengthMedium];
    [myo vibrateWithLength:TLMVibrationLengthShort];
}
```